# How can fix this error while trying to upload a file to a online database using JSF 2.2?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, tomcat

I'm trying to include functionality in my application that would permit import of data from CSV and XML format into a database table in my database schema.

Below is what I've coded so far

```
  import java.io.FileOutputStream;

  import java.io.IOException;

  import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

  import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

  import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;

  import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

  import org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadedFile;

  import java.io.File;


 @ManagedBean (name="importBean")
 @SessionScoped

public class ImportBean {

private UploadedFile uploadedFile;
private String uploadedFileContents;
private String fileName;
private long fileSize;
private String fileContentType;

public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
    return uploadedFile;
}
public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
}
public String getUploadedFileContents() {
    return uploadedFileContents;
}
public void setUploadedFileContents(String uploadedFileContents) {
    this.uploadedFileContents = uploadedFileContents;
}
public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
public long getFileSize() {
    return fileSize;
}
public void setFileSize(long fileSize) {
    this.fileSize = fileSize;
}
public String getFileContentType() {
    return fileContentType;
}
public void setFileContentType(String fileContentType) {
    this.fileContentType = fileContentType;
}



public void processFileUpload() 

{
    uploadedFileContents = null;
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    String path = ec.getRealPath("/");

    File tempFile = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try {

        fileName = uploadedFile.getName();
        fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getName());
        fileSize = uploadedFile.getSize();
        fileContentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();

        tempFile = new File(path + fileName);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        fos.close();

        }
    catch (IOException e)
    {e.getMessage();}   
}
}
```

The code for JSP is as shown below

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <title>s16g26 File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <f:view>

     <h:form enctype = "multipart/form-data">

     <h:outputText value = "Select a File to Upload">
     </h:outputText>
     <h:inputFile value = "#{importBean.uploadedFile}">
     </h:inputFile>

     <h:commandButton type = "submit" value = "Upload"
     action = "#{importBean.processFileUpload}">
     </h:commandButton>

     </h:form>

     </f:view>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Upon execution I get an error on the jsp code line .

The error states Cannot convert `org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.util.HttpPartWrapper@39e0b28f` of type class `org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.util.HttpPartWrapper` to interface `org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadedFile`

I have no idea how to tackle this error and also following the upload, I am unsure of how to dynamically create tables in the database without mentioning the column names and column types. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the complete stack trace?

Comment: HttpPartWrapper ist not of type UploadedFile which seems to be expected as some unknown code place (missing stack trace).

Comment: You should assign it to a `Part` property. See the duplicate for the correct kickoff code snippet.